# How can I use an ontology schema to classify triples?

Tags: classification, natural-language, knowledge-discovery

I have extracted some triples from text using REBEL an information extraction technic. How do I automatically establish where these triples fit into my pre-existing ontology? How can I use the ontologies schema?